# SEM variances of residuals fixed to 1?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to perform structural equations with two second-order latent variables and five first order latent variables (since "a picture is worth a thousand words" I pasted my model below). To perform SEM correctly, I follow steps decribed in a book by Barbara Byrne(2010).

My questions are:

1. Is it reasonable to fix variances of first order factor
   residuals (res_F1--res_F5) to 1?
2. Does the choice of reference class (for
   setting regression weights to 1) is so crucial? Because, sometimes I
   get some results or sometimes AMOS "says" that variance of res_F4 is
   negative, which I don't know how to interpret it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions you ask are those of identifying the scale of the latent variables. One possible set of answers is:

1. No, you keep these error variances freely estimated. The scale of `F1` is given by `Q`; the scale of `F2` is given by `C`; etc. Adding a fixed variance to that will definitely lead to weird results.
2. Yes, it is important to choose the variable that is well connected to the underlying factor. To figure out which variable to use as the scale anchor, I would first run the four single-factor models separately fixing the variance of the factors to 1, and look for the variable that has the highest standardized coefficient (or equivalently the highest $R^2$) to use as the anchor in the big model.

Another possible set of answers is:

1. Yes, you would want to fix these variances to 1, and then also
2. You need to free up all of the factor loadings.

That way, your latent variable is scaled by its residual term, and you don't have to agonize over the best measure to use as the scaling factor.

See also [Gonzalez and Griffin 2001](http://psycnet.apa.org/index.cfm?fa=buy.optionToBuy&id=2001-18292-004), although I think they simply stumbled upon the [finite sample sensitivity](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/9689118) of [Wald tests](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/890474) to reparameterization... a not-terribly-well-known phenomenon even among well-trained statisticians.

Negative values of error variances are spooky indeed. These are sometimes called Heywood cases. Ken Bollen and I have summarized what we knew about them in [this paper](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/10844983).

Comment: Since I posted this question two days ago and didn't stop thinking about solution, one more issue has raised my doubts. A friend of mine told me to fix variances of res_F1 - res_F5 not to 1, but to 0. Then it worked. I did set parameteres of res_F1--res_F5 to 0, and I obtained chi_squared statistics and there was no negative variances. Anyway, the fact that it works, does not mean that it makes sense or it is right. So my question is like Hamlet's one: should I or should I not set 0 to res_F1--res_F5, or maybe I should set the regression weights of first-order factors' residuals error?

Comment: @Kazimierz, post this as an update to your original question. This is not a forum that people read top to bottom, or whatever. Additional important information should be in your main post. As a side note, the idea to set residual variances to zeroes is ridiculous. Do you really believe that there is no regression error in your latent variable model? I don't. If I were a reviewer looking at the paper that did this, I would simply stop at that place and write a single line rejection (or major revision) note saying, `The authors should relax their error variances.`

Comment: Respectfully, but an advice says that "use comment to ask for more information or suggest improvements". This is the reason for which I did not update my post, but simply.. asked for more info... even if my questions seemed ridiculous.

Comment: This particular advice is aimed at all other people who are looking at your question; it rather reads as "There are two places for you to post something to: the comment box and the answer box. If you need a clarification from the original poster, post it as a comment, not as an answer". These comments are supposed to go with the original question. The comment you posted refers to the original question rather than my answer, that's why I recommended that you edit your original question.